# dynamic cast from father to child

Tags: c++, oop

I have created three classes (creature , dragon , wizard) dragon and wizard inherit from the creature class when I do a dynamic cast like this

```
void dragon::atk(creature *creat){
if(dynamic_cast<dragon*>(creat))
    //
```

cannot dynamic_cast 'creat' (of type 'class creature*') to type 'class dragon*' (source type is not polymorphic)|

I've searched a lot but don't know why this error occur

Comment: It means `creature` must have at least one virtual function. It should be at least destructor in your case.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You say `dragon` inherits from `creature` ? code or it didnt happen :P

Comment: it works after I make the virtual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` generally [requires polymorphic types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.dynamic.cast#6). That means the types involved must have at least one virtual member function (can be a destructor).

Comment: Please flag/vote to close obvious duplicates.

Comment: thx bro it works now